# Mapping nested object with mapstruct

Tags: java, spring, mapstruct

i create mapping like below. How to map flat dto object properties like (street, city, etc) to nested address in domain object. When I try to I've got an error:

> [ERROR] diagnostic:  Unknown property "address.postalCode" in return
>   type.
>               @Mapping(source = "city", target = "address.city"),

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {})
public interface CompanyMapper {
    @Mappings({
            @Mapping(source = "id", target = "id"),
            @Mapping(source = "street", target = "address.street"),
            @Mapping(source = "city", target = "address.city"),
            @Mapping(source = "postalCode", target = "address.postalCode"),
            @Mapping(source = "province", target = "address.province"),
    })
    DomainObject map(DtoObject dto);
```

And classes...

```
public class Address {
            private String street;
            private Integer streetNumber;
            private String city;
            private String postalCode;
            private String province;
            //getters and setters
    }
public class DomainObject {
        private String id;
        private Address address;
        //getters and setters
}

public class DtoObject {
        private String id;
        private String street;
        private String city;
        private String postalCode;
        private String province;
        //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Nesting on the target side as you are trying to use it is not supported yet. There's a feature request for this ([issue #389](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/389)), but we did not yet get to implementing this.

Comment: so is there any other solution to that issue?
I think that gonna works if the expression is in the source !

Comment: @Gunnar Nesting on the Target side is still not supported? and if yes, then this "target side nesting" is supported with lombok out of the box?

Comment: it's possible using  @InheritInverseConfiguration

Comment: Issue gas bene closed.It works in 1.10. However not flawless. Checkout #1011.

Comment: fortunately, that issue has also been solved in the meantime @lrkwz

Answer (score 2):

I could not find a way to do that in one method. Here is my solution :

```
@Mapper
public interface DtoObjectMapper {

    Address toAddress(DtoObject dtoObject);

    DomainObject toDomainObject(DtoObject dtoObject, Address address);

}
```

while using ;

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

    @Autowired
    private DtoObjectMapper dtoObjectMapper;

    public DomainObject convert(DtoObject dtoObject) {
        return dtoObjectMapper.toDomainObject(dtoObject, dtoObjectMapper.toAddress(dtoObject));
    }
}
```